# SQL update not running, reasons unknown

Tags: sql

I am trying to run an update and for reasons I cannot figure out why it is not running.

The error:

```
Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE EventID = '2'' at line 4
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the syntax.

```
 $query = " 
      UPDATE event 
      SET AssignedTo = '$AssignedTo',Project = '$Project',Category = '$EventCategory',
      Status = '$Status',Services = '$EventServices',Priority = '$EventPriority',
      WHERE EventID = '$ID' ";


    try {  
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
       $stmt->execute(); 


    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die( "Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 

    die("                      Changes Submitted"); 
}
```

Comment: You have a comma at the end of the previous line.

Comment: Looking at it here i see an extra comma

Comment: FFS lol 25 mins for a comma

Answer (score 2):

This requires formatting the text, so it is too long for a comment.

If you format your queries neatly, then you can avoid or at least minimize such problems:

```
UPDATE event 
      SET AssignedTo = '$AssignedTo',
          Project = '$Project',
          Category = '$EventCategory',
          Status = '$Status',
          Services = '$EventServices',
          Priority = '$EventPriority',
-------------------------------------^
      WHERE EventID = '$ID';
```

The lines for the query don't scroll off the page, making it easier to spot an extra comma.